# Unusual CHECKPOINT behaviour in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I'm hoping to get some opinions on what could be the cause of strange checkpoint behaviour in SQL Server.

I have a database which is in the SIMPLE recovery model and starts at 10 GB in size. The database is on a SQL Server 2017 instance and is configured for Indirect Checkpoints with target_recovery_time_in_seconds set to 60.

We have alerts that trigger on transaction log percent usage (70%) which is typically when an internal CHECKPOINT would occur. We then continued to receive alerts as the transaction log continued to grow and eventually registered 99% full but no further growth occurred.

The log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases showed ACTIVE TRANSACTION as the reason why the last attempted log truncation failed. I confirmed that there were no active transactions running using close to all relevant DMVs.

Issuing a CHECKPOINT manually cleared the wait_desc and truncated the log.

My theory is that the database had an active transaction at the time when log truncation was last attempted either when 70% log usage was breached or after that point when the target dirty buffers to be flushed to disk was reached. In either case there was an active transaction at that point which prevented log truncation. Since that last checkpoint there was minimal activity resulting in no further checkpoint attempt due to not reaching the dirty buffers threshold therefore even though there is now no active transaction log truncation would can't take place until a CHECKPOINT was issued.

I intend to place Trace Flag 3502 on to see the checkpoint activity when this transaction is supposedly running.

Has anyone ever encountered this behaviour, or knows if SQL Server has a back off configured for running checkpoints when above 70% transaction log usage even as the log continues to fill?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just some observations. 1.>>>The database is configured for Indirect Checkpoints with target_recovery_time_in_seconds set to 60<<< Why did you make this configuration? In case you just left the default recovery interval = 0 and target_recovery_time_in_seconds = 0 automatic checkpoints would be used with target recovery interval of 1 minute

Comment: target_recovery_time_in_seconds set to 60 is the default value in SQL Server 2016 for indirect checkpointing, that's just what the databases were created with. An internal checkpoint still would've occurred at 70% free space to flush the dirty pages and attempted log truncation but was met by an active transaction.

I think it's strange that SQL Server would only fire once on the condition of log percent used at 70%. Because in this particular instance it seems that insufficient pages were dirtied after the transaction completed resulting in no CHECKPOINT and therefore no log truncation.

Comment: The default value for target_recovery_time_in_seconds is 0 (which means 60 seconds), the recovery interval default value is also 0 (that means 1 minute), however, they are both set to 0, and if you don't toch them **automatic** checkpoints are used. But if you chanche target_recovery_time_in_seconds, **indirect** checkpoints are used. See **Interaction of the TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME and 'recovery interval' Options** here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-recovery-interval-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: When indirect checkpoints are used, they are based on the amount of dirty pages produced since the last checkpoint, when automatic checkpoints are used they trigger in base of the log records produced since the last checkpoint, that is defferent

Comment: I know you may be trying to be helpful but 60 seconds is the default as of SQL Server 2016 (see: https://littlekendra.com/2016/06/14/target-recovery-interval-and-indirect-checkpoint-new-default-of-60-seconds-in-sql-server-2016/).

I understand the difference and have explained that in my post and response. The key here is the **internal** checkpoint at 70% used space has triggered once but log truncation couldn't occur because of wait_desc ACTIVE TRANSACTION. After the transaction completed no further internal checkpoint was triggered in response to log % usage.

Comment: The threshold of 70% is used by AUTOMATIC checkpoint, not by internal. Internal checkpoints are checkpoints used by dbcc checkdb/checktable (when database snepshot is created), when shutdown happens, when full/diff backup is performed

Comment: >>>but 60 seconds is the default as of SQL Server 2016<<< The default is 0. It means 60 seconds, but it's 0. I'll paste it to your question, please delete it when you see it

Comment: We're going to have to disagree on it being 0 as default because you can simply check the model database on any SQL Server 2016 installation since this is the default value for indirect checkpointing.

Anyway, that aside you're correct the Microsoft documentation does suggest that 70% threshold is a feature of Automatic checkpoints but I guess in this instance I had 99% transaction log usage and it still couldn't truncate until after the transaction completed and by then there weren't enough dirty pages not already flushed to disk.

Comment: The reason for my confusion in regards to the Internal checkpointing was down to (https://www.sqlshack.com/database-checkpoints-enhancements-sql-server-2016/) stating that the 70% breach was not just a feature of automatic checkpointing.

Comment: @sepupic, thanks for your help in clarifying automatic checkpoints and the 70% log usage threshold.

I created a test database and with a test workload running I monitored the Checkpoint pages/sec (automatic) and Background writer pages/sec (indirect) PerfMon counters. Even though the 70% threshold was breached numerous times in the test, no value was registered for Checkpoint pages/sec.

Comment: Did you try to enable automatic checkpoints by setting TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME to 0? I checked model database and see it's set to 60 there, all my databases were restored from previous versions so they still have 0 and use automatic checkpoints, I don't have problems like yours

Comment: I could actually try to run the same test with automatic checkpoints set to see. 

I think in this particular instance the same issue would occur with log truncation being blocked by the active transaction. When the transaction completes, the number of log records to be flushed may still be considered less than the recoverable in 60 second 'recovery interval' threshold preventing an automatic checkpoint occurring and the log from being truncated.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @sepupic, the 70% log space usage issued checkpoint is a characteristic of automatic checkpoints and not internal checkpoints (see comments on question).

The simple reason for this noticed behaviour is that the indirect checkpoints would've responded to dirty page threshold breaches while the active transaction continued to execute. The active transaction prevented log truncation from occurring with the checkpoints and so the transaction log continued to grow.

Between the time that the last indirect checkpoint and the previously active transaction (that prevented log truncation) completed there were insufficient dirty pages to trigger an indirect checkpoint to occur.

Hence why the last log_reuse_wait_desc remained ACTIVE TRANSACTION even when no active transaction was found upon investigation and that the log file usage was immediately cleared by a manual CHECKPOINT command being issued.